# How to display the pandas rolling window like its code?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Yeah, I revised my pandas dataframe sample in my question from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64089678/how-to-print-rolling-window-equation-process-from-pandas-dataframe-in-python):
But this time the question is different

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d=({'A':['2020-01-01','2020-01-02','2020-01-03','2020-01-04','2020-01-05','2020-01-06','2020-01-07','2020-01-08','2020-01-09','2020-01-10'],
'B':[100,110,120,175,164,169,155,153,156,200]})
df=pd.DataFrame(d)

            A    B
0  2020-01-01  100
1  2020-01-02  110
2  2020-01-03  120
3  2020-01-04  175
4  2020-01-05  164
5  2020-01-06  169
6  2020-01-07  155
7  2020-01-08  153
8  2020-01-09  156
9  2020-01-10  200
```

I knew pandas rolling window code be like (for my case):
`df['sums']=df['B'].rolling(window=3, center=False).sum()`

```
            A    B   sums
0  2020-01-01  100    NaN #Here's the question:
1  2020-01-02  110    NaN #Why the rolling windows NaN is just 2, but the rolling window code is 3
2  2020-01-03  120  330.0
3  2020-01-04  175  405.0
4  2020-01-05  164  459.0
5  2020-01-06  169  508.0
6  2020-01-07  155  488.0
7  2020-01-08  153  477.0
8  2020-01-09  156  464.0
9  2020-01-10  200  509.0
Name: sum, dtype: float64
```

and i want to be make it like this:

```
0  2020-01-01  100    NaN # To display rolling window
1  2020-01-02  110    NaN # Like the code
2  2020-01-03  120    NaN # Not 2 but 3 NaNs
3  2020-01-04  175  330.0
4  2020-01-05  164  405.0
5  2020-01-06  169  459.0
6  2020-01-07  155  508.0
7  2020-01-08  153  488.0
8  2020-01-09  156  477.0
9  2020-01-10  200  464.0
10 2020-01-11  NaN  509.0
```

Is there a way to do it? I try to add `NaN=np.nan` it become like this:

```
1  2020-01-02  110    NaN
2  2020-01-03  120    NaN 
3  2020-01-04  175  330.0
.
.
9  2020-01-10  200  464.0
10 2020-01-11  NaN  509.0
0  2020-01-01  100    NaN
```

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: The first two windows don't contain three values, but the third window does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two `NaN`'s at the beginning of the series because at that point you don't have enough data for rolling (1 and 2 instead of 3). Starting from row `3` you do.

If you want `3` starting `NaN`, chain your rolling code with a `shift`:

```
df['sums']=df['A'].rolling(window=3, center=False).sum().shift()
```

Output:

```
     A   sums
0  100    NaN
1  110    NaN
2  120    NaN
3  175  330.0
4  164  405.0
5  169  459.0
6  155  508.0
7  153  488.0
8  156  477.0
9  200  464.0
```