# How to create a new column from merging two or more column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I created a sample data frame like this:

```
     A   B    A+B
0    1   2    3
1    9   60   69
2    20  400  420
```

And i want to display the process like this: Yeah the process like [my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64089678/how-to-print-rolling-window-equation-process-from-pandas-dataframe-in-python) but without rolling window stuff this time

```
     A   B    A+B   Equation
0    1   2    3     1+2  
1    9   60   69    9+60     #the expectation
2    20  400  420   20+400
```

Assuming column A and Column B is created from separated columns like this:

```
d={'A':[1,9,20],'B':[2,60,400]}
```

Andhere's some code that i tried:

```
df['A+B']=df['A']+df['B']

df['Process']=str(df['A'])+str(df['B'])
```

Here's the output:

```
    A    B
0   1    2
1   9   60
2  20  400

    A    B  A+B                                            Process
0   1    2    3  0     1\n1     9\n2    20\nName: A, dtype: int...
1   9   60   69  0     1\n1     9\n2    20\nName: A, dtype: int...
2  20  400  420  0     1\n1     9\n2    20\nName: A, dtype: int... #Is there any step that i missed?
>>>
```

Comment: `df["A"].astype(str)+"+"+df["B"].astype(str)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Henry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9284423/henry-yik) suggested, the best way to achieve what you want is:

```
df['Process'] = df['A'].astype(str) + '+' + df['B'].astype(str)
df
    A   B   A+B Process
0   1   2   3   1+2
1   9   60  69  9+60
2   20  400 420 20+400
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apply function

```
df['Process']= df.apply(lambda row : f"{row['A']}+{row['B']}", axis=1)
```

It works for me.